# Degrees of freedom of a hierarchical model

Tags: nonlinear-regression, parameterization, independence

I have a nonlinear regression model that has two independent parameters, $a$ and $b$, and one dependent parameter, $c$, which is dependent on the independent parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ estimated from a linear regression model. Assuming I have $n$ observations for both models, how many degrees of freedom does my nonlinear model have?

Do I just count the number of independent parameters, which is 4 in this case?